# Black WPF Window when activating it from another application?

Tags: c#, wpf

i am developing a wpf app, but i have a problem 
when i activate my app from another application it shows totally black(demo on the bottom)

this code of activating my window work great but the window shows black

```
class WinApi2
{
    public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 5;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public static void ShowToFront(string windowName)
    {
        IntPtr firstInstance = FindWindow(null, windowName);
        ShowWindow(firstInstance, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        SetForegroundWindow(firstInstance);
    }
}
// Activating my window by calling: 
ShowToFront(".");
```

The result :

[image: who the window it shows]

i found a solution by calling This.Show(); on the Activated Event of my wpf window

```
    public  void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
    }
```

but when doing that the black window still there it shows for a quick time and goes like flash that give a bad locking at the app showing.

i tried the same code to show another app(created with c plus plus) no problem, but the problem is just with wpf apps i think Winforms too !  who can i solver this problem ??

Comment: Is your window empty?

Comment: no it contains listbox and many controls around 12 one

Comment: Try to test your code on an empty window see what's happen tell me back.

Comment: ok thank you , i did. the same problem , i try too to change the .net edition but the problem still there

Comment: your code works for me well, tell me about your CPU and graphics

Comment: os :windows 10 ; Cpu : Core2Duo 2GHz ;  Gpu: Intel 4500Mhd 2Gb internal memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105289/discussion-between-henka-programmer-and-bilal).